# Verb agreement and relative clause

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, relative-clauses, conjugations

In relative clause, does the verb agree with noun, even if the subject is relativized?

In other words: which one is correct?

> I love the apple that is still fresh
>
> I love the apple that are still fresh

How about these?

> I eat the apples that is still fresh
>
> I eat the apples that are still fresh

What if I change that into which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the verb must still agree with its subject. This is the same when using either "that" or "which":

> I love the apple that is still fresh. (good)
>   
>  * I love the apple that are still fresh. (wrong)
>   
>  * I eat the apples that is still fresh. (wrong)
>   
>  I eat the apples that are still fresh. (good)

From a syntax perspective, this seems to be evidence that the subject of the relative clause keeps the [+plural] feature from the main clause even though it doesn't appear explicitly.